# Fail to Nvidia GPU passthrough in Ubuntu

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, gpu, qemu

I followed [this post](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/) to setup the passthrough. I also referred some [other articles](http://arseniyshestakov.github.io/vfio-archive/onepage/). I installed the driver following [this article](http://tryingtoprogram.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-install-opencl-for-nvidia-gpus.html).

I tried both the following options for qemu 2.2:

```
-device ioh3420,bus=pcie.0,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1 \                
-device vfio-pci,host=02:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=02:00.1,bus=root.1,addr=00.1 \
-M q35
```

and

```
-device vfio-pci,host=02:00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=02:00.1 \
-vga none
```

When I run `lspci -vv` on the guest:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 760] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Device 196e:0984
    Physical Slot: 0
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
    Region 0: Memory at fc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at e8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Region 3: Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at c000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at fd000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Device 196e:0984
    Physical Slot: 0
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at fd080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

When I run smi:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

On the host:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 760] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Device 196e:0984
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at f9000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at d8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Region 3: Memory at d6000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at cc00 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f8f80000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci

02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Device 196e:0984
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at f8f7c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
```

I've tried to figure it out for several days, rebinding GPU, reinstalling drivers, etc. But I still don't know which step was wrong.

Did I passthrough the GPU successfully? How can I make it work on the guest?

Any help would be very great. Thanks in advance.